# Authentication with JWT in HTTP only cookie without refresh token

Tags: reactjs, security, authentication, cookies, jwt

The motto of the upcoming question is "I don't know what I don't know".
I would like to know if there are downsides or security risks with an authentication implementation.

Right now, I'm storing a JWT in an HTTP only cookie to send it from the client (React application) to the server (Spring Boot/Kotlin application). This removes the XSS vulnerability.

The JWT follows the basic principles (encoded secret, expiration date, issuer check, etc.). The server has servlet filters that check an existing cookie for validity on every request. When signing in via the client, the server responds with a valid JWT:

[image: sign in]

The client will send its cookie with every request, which is furthermore checked for validity by the server's servlet filters on every request. When these checks are positive, the user is authenticated with Spring Security.

As described above, the JWT expires after 1 hour, 1 day, or whatever is configured. That's why I need to refresh it some way or another. Now, instead of using a refresh token and placing it in the client's local storage, I decided to just make a small request to the server and create a new JWT, which is send back via the response again:

[image: refresh]

Again, when the `refresh` endpoint is called, the servlet filters will check for validity. So only an already authenticated user will receive a new JWT token that way. Some invalid JWT will not receive a new JWT.
I'm calling this endpoint from the client in an interval and therefore regularly extend the expiration date of the JWT inside the cookie.

---

What I'm aware of:

- With the current refresh mechanism, an access token can be valid indefinitely (when the user is signed in regularly).
- I also don't persist valid tokens or sessions in the database, so I can't really invalidate specific user sessions "globally" that way, as the cookie is the only source of truth. But this has nothing to do with the refresh token, I could create such whitelist/blacklist via the user ID instead.

If something really bad happens, I could still

- ...change the expiration date of all JWT to 0, so every authenticated user will be unauthenticated the next time he sends a request.
- ...or I could change the JWT secret, from which one no request will be authenticated anymore.

My question is: Has what I'm doing (replacing the JWT inside the cookie) any more downsides?

Comment: *I'm calling this endpoint from the client in an interval* There's no need, just implement the *sliding expiration* pattern, where you just check upon every request if the half (or more) of the token lifespan has passed and then reissue the token. Otherwise looks good.